# What do $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{2x+1-2i}$ and $\frac12\log(2x+1-2i)$ mean?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

Suppose we want to evaluate
$$I=\oint_C\frac{dz}{z+\frac12}$$
where $C$ is the unit square with diagonal corners at $-1-i$ and $1+i$. If we let $z:=re^{it}-\frac12$, then
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2rie^{it}}{2re^{it}-1+1}dt=2i\pi$$
but one way in my textbook is to let $z:=x+iy,dz=dx+idy$, in this case
$$I=\int_{-1}^1\frac{2dx}{2x+1-2i}+\int_{-1}^1\frac{2idy}{3+2iy}+\int_1^{-1}\frac{2dx}{2x+1+2i}+\int_1^{-1}\frac{2idy}{-1+2iy}$$
Now, for example, in first integral can we write
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{2x+1-2i}=\frac12\log(2x+1-2i)|_{-1}^1=\frac12\log(3-2i)-\frac12\log(-1-2i)?$$

$\frac{dx}{2x+1-2i}$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$ and I used techniques of real integration to find antidervative, so I can't understand that if this can be true or this $\log$ is a real logarithm or complex?? and if this is true, then by summing these four integrals, we arrive to $0\neq 2i\pi$? So what do
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{2x+1-2i}\,\textrm{and}\,\frac12\log(2x+1-2i)$$
mean??

Comment: The complex logarithm is multivalued.  You will need to choose a branch cut to restrict the logarithm to be single valued.

Comment: @Dr.MV $\frac1{2x+1-2i}$ is a function from$\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$. If we write $\int\frac{dx}{2x+1-2i}=\frac12\log(2x+1-2i)$ we used techniques of real integration, so I don't know how this can be true?

Comment: @Dr.MV So I can't understand that this logarithm is real or complex??

Comment: I've posted a solution, the second part of which used the complex logarithm.  Note that caution needs to be taken when integrating through the branch cut.  The complex logarithm is singular along that cut and its values infinitesimally above and below the cuts differ by $2\pi i$. -Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be the contour integral defined by

$$\begin{align}
I&=\oint_C \frac{1}{z+1/2}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(x+1/2)-i}\,dx+\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{3/2+iy}\,i\,dy\\\\
&-\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(x+1/2)+i}\,dx-\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{-1/2+iy}\,i\,dy \tag 1
\end{align}$$

We can proceed using real analysis.  Proceeding accordingly, we can write $I$ in $(1)$ as

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x+1/2)+i}{(x+1/2)^2+1}\,dx+\int_{-1}^1 \frac{3/2-iy}{(3/2)^2+y^2}\,i\,dy\\\\
&-\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x+1/2)-i}{(x+1/2)^2+1}\,dx-\int_{-1}^1 \frac{-1/2+iy}{(1/2)^2+y^2}\,i\,dy \\\\
&=2i\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(x+1/2)^2+1}\,dx+\frac32 i \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(3/2)^2+y^2}\,dy+\frac12 i\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{(1/2)^2+y^2}\,dy\\\\
&=2i(\arctan(3/2)+\arctan(1/2))+2i\arctan(2/3)+2i\arctan(2)\\\\
&=2i\pi
\end{align}$$

as expected!

---

Alternatively, we can evaluate each of the integrals in $(1)$ using the complex logarithm function.  To do so requires choosing a branch cut to ensure that the logarithm is single valued.  We choose the branch cut of $\log(z)$ for the  principal branch of the logarithm, taken along the negative real axis.  There, we have

$$\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i\arg(z) \tag{$|z|>0,-\pi\le \arg(z)< \pi$}$$

Note from $(1)$ that the integration path $C$ crosses the chosen branch cut at $z=-1$.  Therefore, we need to evaluate the fourth integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ as follows.

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{-1/2+iy}\,i\,dy&=\int_{-1}^{0^-}\frac{1}{-1/2+iy}\,i\,dy+\int_{0^+}^{1}\frac{1}{-1/2+iy}\,i\,dy\\\\
&=\log(-1/2+i0^-)-\log(-1/2-i)+\log(-1/2+i)-\log(-1/2+i0^+)\\\\
&=\log(1/2)-i\pi-\log(-1/2+i)+\log(-1/2+i)-\log(1/2)-i\pi\\\\
&=-2i\pi -\log(-1/2+i)+\log(-1/2+i) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

The first, second, and third integrals in $(1)$ are respectively

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(x+1/2)-i}\,dx&=\log(3/2-i)-\log(-1/2-i) \tag 3\\\\
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(x+1/2)+i}\,dx&=\log(3/2+i)-\log(-1/2+i)\tag 4\\\\
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{3/2+iy}\,i\,dy&=\log(3/2+i)-\log(3/2-i) \tag 5\\\\
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(2)-(5)$ into $(1)$, we find that

$$I=2\pi i$$

thereby recovering the result obtained with real analysis!

Comment: Thanks, but the final answer shouldn't be $i\pi$?

Comment: The final answer is $2\pi i$ not $\pi i$.  The analysis in the OP needs a factor of $2$ in the numerator.